# converting a string to enum from a binary file

Tags: c#, enums, record

I get the following error whenever I try to read a string value from a binary file (where the string values is an enum type)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Requested value 'Bulldog' was not found.

Note, my first record reads fine and appears in the console window, but my second record (with the title 'Bulldog') is causing the issue I believe.

As you can see, `TGenreTypes` are declared as follows.

```
enum TGenreTypes
{
    Romance,
    SciFi,
    Action,
    Thriller,
    Horror,
    Adventure
};

struct TBook
{ 
    public string author;
    public string title;
    public TGenreTypes genre;
    public int bookid;
};
```

Then, in the read statement, I've used `Enum.Parse` as you can see below:

```
 do
 {
     //Now write variable contents to file
     myBooks.title = readerFromFile.ReadString();
     myBooks.author = readerFromFile.ReadString();
     myBooks.genre = (TGenreTypes) Enum.Parse(typeof(TGenreTypes),readerFromFile.ReadString());
     myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
     Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", myBooks.title);
     Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", myBooks.author);
     Console.WriteLine("Genre: {0}", myBooks.genre);
     Console.WriteLine("BookID: {0}", myBooks.bookid);
 }
 while (currentFile.Position <= currentFile.Length);
```

However, i get the aforementioned error message when the it attempts to read the second record from file. Incidently, the title of the second record is 'Bulldog'...which is weird because it breaks at the 'genre parsing' line.

Here is the complete program, which is still giving me the error:

```
namespace Reading_from_Binary_File
{
    class Program
    {
        enum TGenreTypes
        { 
            None = 0,
            Romance,
            SciFi,
            Action,
            Thriller,
            Horror,
            Adventure,
            Fantasy
        };

        struct TBook
        {
            public string author;
            public string title;
            public TGenreTypes genre;
            public int bookid;
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream currentFile;
            BinaryReader readerFromFile;

            currentFile = new FileStream("Test.bin", FileMode.Open);
            readerFromFile = new BinaryReader(currentFile);

            TBook myBooks;

            do
            {
                //Now write variable contents to file
                myBooks.title = readerFromFile.ReadString();
                myBooks.author = readerFromFile.ReadString();
                myBooks.genre = (TGenreTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(TGenreTypes),readerFromFile.ReadString());
                myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", myBooks.title);
                Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", myBooks.author);
                Console.WriteLine("Genre: {0}", myBooks.genre);
                Console.WriteLine("BookID: {0}", myBooks.bookid);
            }
            while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length);

            //close the streams
            readerFromFile.Close();
            currentFile.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you intend `myBooks.genre.ToString()`? Are you trying to write the enum to the file as a string (that's what your title says) or do you want to write it as an int?

Comment: String is fine and solves. If I was to write to int, would that be gettype() ?

Comment: No, you'd just cast it. `(int)myBooks.genre`

Comment: From what you say, you have two extra lines in your file, and then you're trying to incorrectly parse the book name as the enumeration. Post the code where you save the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx). In this way, you can avoid exceptions with wrong values:

```
TGenreTypes genre;

if (Enum.TryParse(readerFromFile.ReadString(), out genre))
{
    myBooks.genre = genre;
}
else
{
    // Handle when parse error if needed
}
```

Aditionally I suggest you to add a "None" entry with zero value to your enumeration. It's a good practice and you can leave it as the default value for your records with errors casting the enum. Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/05/18/134208.aspx) for more about this.

```
enum TGenreTypes
{
    None = 0,
    Romance,
    SciFi,
    Action,
    Thriller,
    Horror,
    Andventure
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as in your related question [Reading from binary file error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34616165/2921691).
For the sake of solving the mystery for others once again the answer:

Try exchanging

```
myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
```

with

```
myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt32();
```

as by default the `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`.

In your structure

```
struct TBook
{
    public string author;
    public string title;
    public string genre; //TGenreTypes genre;
    public int bookid;
};
```

you have specified `int bookid` which would then be a `System.Int32`.
So reading just `2 bytes` instead of `4 bytes` will result in having `2 bytes` left in the stream. So the loop won't break. In the loop you will then try to read another "set" of data which isn't there (just the 2 bytes).