# Reading from a binary file error

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

Trying to read simple record structure from Binary file, but get the following error message.  What is the problem?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Reading_from_Binary_File
{
    class Program
    {
        struct TBook
        {
            public string author;
            public string title;
            public string genre; //TGenreTypes genre;
            public int bookid;
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream currentFile;
            BinaryReader readerFromFile;
            currentFile = new FileStream("Test.bin", FileMode.Open);
            readerFromFile = new BinaryReader(currentFile);

            TBook myBooks;
            do
            {
                //Now read from file and write to console window
                 myBooks.title = readerFromFile.ReadString();
                 myBooks.author = readerFromFile.ReadString();
                 myBooks.genre = readerFromFile.ReadString();
                // myBooks.genre = (TGenreTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(TGenreTypes),readerFromFile.ReadString());
                myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", myBooks.title);
                Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", myBooks.author);
                Console.WriteLine("Genre: {0}", myBooks.genre);
                Console.WriteLine("BookID: {0}", myBooks.bookid);
            }
            while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length);

            //close the streams
            currentFile.Close();
            readerFromFile.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I also tried

```
while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length);
{
    ...
}
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: I believe the problem is clear... you're trying to read past the end of the file. Do you have a sample file that has the problem you're describing?

Comment: Try reversing your do...while, making it a while..do. With a do...while, the "safety test" can come too late - you've already "do'd" when you should have "don't" if you get my drift.

Comment: @ B.Clay Shannon  Have just tried that and I get the same error message.

Comment: I@  SuperOil   If it helps, I could show you the BinaryWriter program I use to create the binary file?

Comment: @user3396486: I've posted an answer which I guess will solve your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exchanging

```
myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt16();
```

with

```
myBooks.bookid = readerFromFile.ReadInt32();
```

as by default the `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`.

In your structure

```
struct TBook
{
    public string author;
    public string title;
    public string genre; //TGenreTypes genre;
    public int bookid;
};
```

you have specified `int bookid` which would then be a `System.Int32`.
So reading just `2 bytes` instead of `4 bytes` will result in having `2 bytes` left in the stream. So the loop won't break. In the loop you will then try to read another "set" of data which isn't there (just the 2 bytes).

Comment: Thank you Markus. You nailed it.

Comment: @user3396486: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your do...while to a while (do) like so:

```
while (currentFile.Position < currentFile.Length)            
{
    //Now read from file and write to console window
    . . .
}
```

In this way, the test is made as to reaching the "danger zone" prior to actually attempting to access that position. If you wait to check until after the attempt, the last attempt (as you found out) will fail.

You might want to czech [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s3p8.html) out.